# Issues with slicing multidimensional list

Tags: python

I know how to slice regular list but using multi list is driving me nuts.
I have a 9x9 square that im trying to run checks on each 3x3 square.

```
x x x | x x x | x x x
x x x | x x x | x x x 
x x x | x x x | x x x
---------------------
x x x | x x x | x x x
x x x | x x x | x x x 
x x x | x x x | x x x
---------------------
x x x | x x x | x x x
x x x | x x x | x x x 
x x x | x x x | x x x
```

Im having to brute force it. I know there is an easier and nicer way of doing it instead of having to have

```
square_1 = board[0][:3] + board[1][:3] + board[2][:3]
square_2 = board[0][3:6] + board[1][3:6] + board[2][3:6]
square_3 = board[0][6:9] + board[1][6:9] + board[2][6:9]
```

Comment: Could you use a numpy matrix for the problem?

Comment: I have never used numpy :( Any good resources?

Comment: Actually scratch that. I'll post an answer without numpy.

Answer (score 1):

```
board = [[10*r + c for c in range(1,10)] for r in range(1,10)]
squares = [[board[3*r + i][3*c + j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)] for r,c in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)]
```

Output:

```
In [18]: board = [[10*r + c for c in range(1,10)] for r in range(1,10)]

In [19]: board
Out[19]: 
[[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
 [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
 [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
 [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
 [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
 [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]

In [20]: squares = [[board[3*r + i][3*c + j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)] for r,c in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)]

In [21]: squares
Out[21]: 
[[11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33],
 [14, 15, 16, 24, 25, 26, 34, 35, 36],
 [17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 37, 38, 39],
 [41, 42, 43, 51, 52, 53, 61, 62, 63],
 [44, 45, 46, 54, 55, 56, 64, 65, 66],
 [47, 48, 49, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69],
 [71, 72, 73, 81, 82, 83, 91, 92, 93],
 [74, 75, 76, 84, 85, 86, 94, 95, 96],
 [77, 78, 79, 87, 88, 89, 97, 98, 99]]
```

Now, if you wanted the squares to also be two-dimensional, then you could do this:

```
squares = [[[board[3*r + i][3*c + j] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)] for r,c in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)]
```

Output:

```
Out[22]: 
[[[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]],
 [[14, 15, 16], [24, 25, 26], [34, 35, 36]],
 [[17, 18, 19], [27, 28, 29], [37, 38, 39]],
 [[41, 42, 43], [51, 52, 53], [61, 62, 63]],
 [[44, 45, 46], [54, 55, 56], [64, 65, 66]],
 [[47, 48, 49], [57, 58, 59], [67, 68, 69]],
 [[71, 72, 73], [81, 82, 83], [91, 92, 93]],
 [[74, 75, 76], [84, 85, 86], [94, 95, 96]],
 [[77, 78, 79], [87, 88, 89], [97, 98, 99]]]
```

Thus, `squares[0]` is the following two-dimensional list:

```
[[11, 12, 13], 
 [21, 22, 23], 
 [31, 32, 33]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```
square_1 = [board[i][j] for i in range(0,3) for j in range(0,3)]
square_2 = [board[i][j] for i in range(0,3) for j in range(2,6)]
...
```

Or in a slightly more elegant way:

```
def square(a,b):
    square[a][b] = [board[i][j] for i in range(3*a-3,3*a) for j in range(3*b-3, 3*b)]
```

Comment: Is there anyway of getting it down to a single variable or someway of looping through while still doing a 3x3 square?

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to redesign your data structure to use only a single list with 81 elements. The value at `x,y` would be stored at index `x+9y` in the one-dimensional list. Your squares would then be:

```
squares = [[board[x+3*i+9*y+27*j] for y, x in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)]
           for j, i in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)]
```

This method of representation is very handy, as you can easily calculate the row, column and square an index belongs to with just a few simple calculations (I'm guessing you're solving Sudoku, so you'll need these):

```
row = index // 9
column = index % 9
square = index // 3 % 3 + index // 27 * 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Fundamentally, there is no way to optimize the syntax of list indexing without something like [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). However, you can use a subroutine.

```
def sumrows(bd, n):
    return bd[0][n:n+3] + bd[1][n:n+3] + bd[2][n:n+3]

square_1 = sumrows(board, 0)
square_2 = sumrows(board, 3)
square_3 = sumrows(board, 6)
```

The NumPy version is far more powerful.

```
def sumrows(bd, x, y):
    return bd[x:x+3,y:y+3]

square_1_1 = sumrows(board, 0, 0)
square_1_2 = sumrows(board, 0, 3)
square_1_3 = sumrows(board, 0, 6)

square_2_1 = sumrows(3, 0)
square_2_2 = sumrows(3, 3)
square_2_3 = sumrows(3, 6)
# ...
```

Comment: Parameters number doesn't match.

Comment: No. sumrows() has 2 arguments, you've passed only 1.